# Increase in (possible) network latency in WCF calls during heavy loads

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

We have a WCF serivce - 'A' which calls an operation on another WCF service 'B'. We have logged the time taken for the operation in 'B' to complete inside both 'A' where the call is made and in 'B' inside the actual operation. 
Under normal load the durations logged in both places are quite similar with difference of only few milliseconds. However under heavy loads, the duration logged inside A exceeds that logged inside B almost by a minute.
Can someone please suggest where could this excess time be spent? 
What tools can I use to verify this?
What would be the best way to fix this based on the most likely cause?